# Unit testing json search results in MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to test a method which returns a Json encoded list of items which are the results of a search against a large dataset:

```
public JsonResult()
{
     List<Stuff> myStuff = new List<Stuff>();
     ListItem item = new ListItem();
     mystuff.Add(item);
     return Json(myStuff, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

My problem is that I only know the first item on the returned list - and depending on the search a different list can be generated each time.

Currently I'm trying to test it by simply comparing the first item returned with the "correct" value, but I don't think this is as robust as I'd like it to be (for example I'll want to test most likely results next etc). Has anybody had a simmilar issues before?

Answer (score 0):

With unit testing you need predictable results. Either override the JsonResult() function to always return the same if it is other functions you are testing, or have a separate url to test against so that the json result is always the same. Then you can have multiple json results which each of them are targeted to test different features/bugs in the calling function.

Answer (score -1):

When unit testing the scope of your test is only the functionality of the specific method you are testing.

Your unit test doesn't test how the method you are writing the test for gets the data. all it wants to test is that the method does with the data what it suppose to.

If your method simply returns a search results, then all you test is that if you execute the method some search result is returned.

In that case you prepare the data you want returned and tell a mocked instance of your search method to return it when your method executes it during the unit test.

If your method does more to the search results than that than you write several unit tests to validate it does as expected.

If you want to test that your layers communicate correctly with each other and data is coming back from the database correctly, you write integration tests, not unit tests.